# git-tfs rcheckin error: New TFS changesets were found

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I was using `git-tfs rcheckin` after cloning the TFVC team project repo from TFS 2015 onto my local machine and using `git rebase --onto master --root otherrepo/master`. (I merged another Git repo into the TFVC repo and fixed merge conflicts).

In the middle of the rcheckin, I had to shut my computer down and used Ctrl-C to quit the rcheckin. When I tried to restart, I used `git-tfs fetch` and there weren't any changes and I also verified that in TFS. However, when I tried to do an rcheckin again, I got the following error:

```
Working with tfs remote: default => $/projectA/main
Fetching changes from TFS to minimize possibility of late conflict...
error: New TFS changesets were found. 
You may be able to resolve this problem. 
Try to rebase HEAD onto latest TFS checkin and repeat rcheckin or alterntively checkins
```

When I used `git-tfs pull --rebase` from this suggestion, [git tfs: How to rcheckin git commits when there is another checkin in tfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921465/git-tfs-how-to-rcheckin-git-commits-when-there-is-another-checkin-in-tfs), it looked like I needed to commit my changes (which seemed a bit odd). Once I committed my changes, I tried to use rcheckin and got the same error about new changesets.

I looked again and there weren't any new TFS changesets introduced since the first rcheckin that I ran, but I'm wondering if there could be some incomplete TFS changeset somewhere on the TFS server that's conflicting. If so, is there a way to delete it? Or do I have to start all over again with a new repo? Is there also a better way to pause an rcheckin (or check in in pieces rather than one big push)?

Comment: It is worth for you to have a double check to be sure that the git-tfs pull --rebase command works with $/projectA/main path.